# C programming UART function incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, embedded

I am using the following C library file to try and send 9 floating point values over UART:
https://github.com/microbuilder/LPC1343CodeBase/blob/master/core/uart/uart.c

In following the example in the comments, I came up with the following code:

```
#define UARTBUFFERSIZE 36 
float testVals[9] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}; //global, just for testing
```

In my main code I have the following line to try and send testVals:

```
uartSend((float *)testVals, UARTBUFFERSIZE); 

main.c:94:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'uartSend' from incompatible pointer type
core/uart/uart.h:67:6: note: expected 'uint8_t *' but argument is of type 'float *'
```

Do I have to use 'uint8_t' type, and will that let me send my floating point values?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to try to explicitly cast from a `float[]` to a `float *` - rather, you may want to explicitly cast from a `float[]` to a `uint8_t *` to in effect say "yes I know what I am doing".  You will indeed need to be careful about the difference in element sizes, but you seem to be handling that.

Comment: Well I wasn't 100% on what I was doing, but I suppose with the given answer things seem fine. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you're only initializing 8 values of your testVals array.  (Missed 0.4 in your sequence.)

Comment: Beware of endianness issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it to `uint8_t*`, it is safe. Your size for floats is set correctly 9 floats -> 9 x 4 bytes.

Comment: @JDS: Btw, when doing embedded programming, you need to keep in mind [endian differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and floating-point representation ([usually IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) on all communicating machines. This means that sometimes casting won't be enough, but you will have to rearrange the bytes manually to match the target system's architecture.

Comment: @Groo You should never comply with the target architecture. The receiver only has to know what order the sender is and then use two different methods.

Comment: Why do you think you will have any control over the other device? Or the protocol? Aren't "sender" and "receiver" relative terms? If you have a device which accepts data using a certain **protocol**, you have to comply with that, period. And transmitting floating point numbers over UART sounds like just the right case for checking what's on the other side. I am not even sure in which case the "shouldn't comply with the target architecture" philosophy would work? You just start sending your native data over the wire, ignoring what the other device expects?

Comment: @Groo You specify the endianness and send the data. You don't need to know target endianness. The receiver gets the data and converts appropriately. ( Next time ask a single question please )

Comment: I have a feeling we're talking about different things. To whom you specify the endianness? Oh, sorry about writing all that, I thought that would help clarify my reasoning. Both your answer and comments are pretty short, so I felt it would speed up things. Well, the first question is probably the most important: Why do you think you will have any control over the other device (or the protocol)?

Comment: "Talk to the hand" attitude makes me think you don't actually have an answer to my question. I hoped highlighting it in bold would make it easier to spot, but you still haven't answered it. :) And, to quote your own article: "What *does* matter is the byte order of a peripheral or encoded data stream". That *does* matter. That's why you need to think about what you're sending or receiving. You will use one function if your protocol is little endian, and the other one if it's big endian. That's why there are *two* functions on that page. The author didn't say "oh, just cast whatever there is".